# omega theme issue

Tags: theming

i am using omega theme in drupal7. i implemented theme sucessfully, but i am facing some serious issue. when i try to login with admin. everthing is working fine. but when i use other account.after login it redirects to me 
http://example.com/user/2/. now then i try to go to home page. it will redirects back to me at http://example.com/user/2/.

when i change my theme it is working fine.

Can anybody tell me what is the problem, or where i need to check actual problem

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on the template.php in your theme directory. Probably is there something which redirects you. Or probably a Rule which is active under certain circumstances ...

Comment: i didnt modify any file. and there is no rules module here